# Assetmanager and Skin dispose of Font(/Skin)

Tags: java, libgdx, dispose

I am using the libgdx AssetManager to load a skin with a custom font.

When I call `assetmanager.dispose()` it throws an Exception:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Pixmap already disposed!    
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.dispose(Pixmap.java:315)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PixmapPacker$Page$1.dispose(PixmapPacker.java:384)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.dispose(BitmapFont.java:315)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.dispose(Skin.java:416)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.unload(AssetManager.java:211)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.clear(AssetManager.java:653)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.dispose(AssetManager.java:621)
```

while trying to dispose the custom font i added. I think that this is because the AssetManager disposes the BitmapFont first and the skin afterwards. But the skin is also trying to dispose the BitmapFont. Switching the order of loading the skin and the BitmapFont is not possible, because the skin needs the BitmapFont in its loading process.

This is where I load the skin and font:

```
    FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
    app.assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
    app.assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));
    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter params = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    params.fontFileName = "font/stay_writer.ttf";
    params.fontParameters.size = 25;
    app.assetManager.load("stay_writer_25.ttf", BitmapFont.class, params);
    app.assetManager.finishLoading();
    // Queue Skin
    app.assetManager.load("skins/uiskin.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    ObjectMap<String, Object> resources = new ObjectMap<String, Object>();
    resources.put("default-font", app.assetManager.get("stay_writer_25.ttf", BitmapFont.class));
    app.assetManager.load("skins/uiskin.json", Skin.class, new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("skins/uiskin.atlas", resources));
```

I am continiously calling `assetmanager.update()` and made sure that the skin gets loaded.

I dispose the AssetManager with:

```
assetManager.dispose();
```

This gives me the `Pixmap already disposed!` error.
I debugged the calls of `BitmapFont.dispose()`. The stacktrace of the first call shows me that the call comes from `assetManager.unload()`, and the second call from `Skin.dispose()` which is called from the `assetManager.unload()` method.

Now i want to know if there is a way to dispose of the skin and the BitmapFont, without them conflicting each other.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like SkinLoader does not tell AssetManager that the passed in `resources` are dependencies, so if one of those resources is also a managed asset, it can lead to the problem you're getting.

So if you don't need the font to be managed by AssetManager, you could simply load it independently so AssetManager won't dispose of it.

Otherwise, I think you will need to remove the resource from the Skin before you unload or dispose of the Skin:

```
skin.remove("stay_writer_25.ttf", BitmapFont.class);
```

Comment: The `assetManager.dispose()` method calls `assetmanager.unload()` for every asset loaded with the assetManager. I tested it but it does not resolve the error. As soon as I dispose of the other asset, I get the error again.

Comment: Ah, I see. From looking at the code, it seems SkinLoader treats the passed in `resources` as if they are not managed by the AssetManager. I'll change the answer.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your answer. What's the difference between adding it as dependency or resource?

Comment: It has to be added as a Skin resource for your Skin to use it. A dependency in the AssetManager means the AssetManager will not dispose the asset that is a dependency until the object that is dependent on it is unloaded. But now that I think about it, that will still result in your font getting disposed twice. I think your only option is to not add it directly to AssetManager. Answer updated.

Comment: I just used a `try catch block`. But I don't like that approach.

Comment: I don't think that's a good approach, because your Skin may not finish disposing of all its resources. It will throw when it gets to the problematic resource, and subsequent resources will leak. Maybe in your case it's OK because the font is your only disposable resource, but still it is a hack.